# kubernetes network model vs. network plugin vs. network policy

Tags: kubernetes

When it comes to networking, I'm quite overwhelmed by the numerous concepts and options.
So my question is: What are the usecases and the differences between these kubernetes concepts?

- [network model](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/)
- [network plugin](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/network-plugins/)
- [network policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/)

**What I've found out so far:**

The documentation of network policy describes the usecase quite clear:

> you want to control traffic flow at the IP address or port level

But Network Policy is not used consistently here: Calico is a [Networking Model in kubernetes doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/) or a Network Policy in Azure Portal (s. image).

[image: Azure Networking]

I suspect, that Azure uses the wrong term here.

But then I still do not understand the difference between model and plugin. Of course it's about managing communication between resources.

Why do I need two different concepts and two configuration options for managing network traffic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's several networking problems that addressed in Kubernetes:

1. Container-to-Container communications
2. Pod-to-Pod communications
3. Pod-to-Service communications
4. External network-to-Service communications

1st problem addressed in container runtime, rest(3rd and 4th covered by [services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) which still depend on underlying network model) solved by Kubernetes network model.

Network model is high level description of how network in Kubernetes is supposed to work, that imposes 3 main requirements:

- Every Pod gets its own IP address
- Pods on a Node can communicate with all Pods on all Nodes without NAT
- Agents on a Node can communicate with all Pods on that Node

This abstract model allows different implementations of actual network layer, for example default network implementation called [kubenet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/network-plugins/#kubenet) or [Calico](https://docs.projectcalico.org/about/about-calico), [Cilium](https://github.com/cilium/cilium), etc.

Network plugin is basically anything that implements [NetworkPlugin](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.19.0/pkg/kubelet/dockershim/network/plugins.go#L54) interface. All network model implementations are actually network plugins, even [default one](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/network-plugins/#kubenet). Of course you can set up [some](https://github.com/containernetworking/plugins/tree/master/plugins/meta/portmap) [additional](https://github.com/containernetworking/plugins/tree/master/plugins/meta/bandwidth) plugins for more features/control over network.

But why Azure mentions `Calico` as network policy? Well, network policies are implemented via network plugins and `kubenet`, `Calico` provide their own implementations of network policies.